# Need to start IIS few times everyday to maintain SQL connection in ASP.NET website

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server

This is an ASP.NET website built with Visual Studio 2010 Premium. The purpose is just for event registration with very small work load like only few people to maximum 10 people use it at the same time.

This ASP.NET website is built in my laptop with Windows 8.1, IIS 6.2, SQL Server 2008 R2 and there is no IIS restart problem in my laptop, no matter I run it in debug mode with Visual Studio or published version.

However, somehow there is a SQL connection problem in live server with published version and I need to restart IIS few times everyday in the live server to solve it. When it works, it works totally fine, but after like minutes or luckily an hour or two, the ASP.NET pages that require SQL connection would just stop working and the only solution is to restart the IIS. The live server setup is Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, and IIS 8.

This is my main task for my job now and please help, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you don't close the connections after you use them. Please share the code where you communicate with the database.

Comment: Can you expand on 'stop working'? Do you get an error or is the page unresponsive? Clearly defining the actual problem is the first step in solving it.

Comment: I use select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where counter_name ='User Connections' to see the connect number. For my localhost testing environment with exact same asp.net codes, the cntr_value is very low around 10 and doesn't grow no matter what I try. But in the live server, with loading sql connection page, the cntr_value grows and then page error with number 146. I have tried few times and it is always 146.

Comment: "page error with number 146" is not something I'm familiar with. You need to keep digging and find a useful error number. There's no way to troubleshoot 'stop working' but there is a way to troubelshoot a useful error message. Is there anything in the console or network tabs (F12)? Is there anything in the  IIS or SQL Logs? If this is your main task for now you need to learn some basic troubleshooting and the first step is looking at looks and defining the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you released database resources in your code?
2. And have you handled failure of obtaining sql connection?

I'm not an ASP.NET developer(using Tomcat and MySQL usually). But according to my experiences, this kind of bug happens when one forget to release some resources(DbConnection, File, etc.). Successive operations to obtain such resources will fail and cause problems. Thus your web-page works fine in a short time after IIS restarted(Sql connections haven't been run out), then crushes(run out of Sql connections).

If you had done both and the problem continues, then I'm wrong. In that case, I suggest you post your code snippet.